# How to access documents of device

Tags: iphone, ios

I want add documents (except images) in email by coding. i know we can access devices image gallery but i want to access documents of the device.

Can we access the documents just like imagepicker?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not access Images from document directory same as device Library *(`by UIImagePickerView`)*

But if you want to get particular image from document directory then use following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *newPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOFImage"]; // put name of image which you want to get it from document directory
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
```

Here **myImage** is image that you want to get it from document directory,

Comment: i dnt want to acces applications document directory

Comment: @gtechtech - if you want to access image such like device library by UIImagePicker that is not possible to access document directory like this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a visual file browser so try **NSOutlineView**.
Check this (similar) question
[Using NSOutlineView as a file browser, starting from a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636416/using-nsoutlineview-as-a-file-browser-starting-from-a-given-directory)
or this tutorial:
http://www.alauda.ro/2012/04/30/nsoutlineview-inside-out/

Or manually handle the files using **NSFileManager** (but it seems this is not what you are looking for, but anyways...)
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Objective-C#Getting__a_Directory_File_Listing

Actually, I don't believe there is anything as easy and simple as UIImagePicker for browsing files and folders so I guess the NSOutlineView will be the best choice for you.